# What are "reverse dependencies" in R?

Tags: r, installation, dependencies, rjson

I have to install the `rjson` package in R and looking at the [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) page that deals with the package I saw that `rjson` has different dependencies:

- **Reverse depends**: couchDB, df2json, edeR, gooJSON, indicoio, kintone, notifyR, RDSTK, Rfacebook, rJython, Rlabkey, rPlant, RYoudaoTranslate, SmarterPoland, sotkanet, source.gist, Storm, streamR, tibbrConnector, zendeskR;
- **Reverse imports**: AntWeb, argparse, BerlinData, blsAPI, Causata, d3Network, db.r, geonames, GetoptLong, ggmap, h2o, helsinki, james.analysis, meteoForecast, mpoly, networkD3, ngramr, nhlscrapr, OpasnetUtils, OutbreakTools, paleobioDB, RAdwords, rbefdata, rClinicalCodes, rfisheries, rglobi, RIGHT, rnrfa, solr, StereoMorph, structSSI, twitteR, vdmR, yhatr;
- **Reverse suggests**:    fuzzyMM, GSIF, installr, mlr, plotKML, rsnps, sorvi, trajectories;

What is the difference among them and do I have to install all of them to use the `rjson` package?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are reverse dependencies, that is these packages depend on `rjson`.
You do not have to install these in order to use `rjson`.

Looking at the [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/alexcb/rjson/blob/master/rjson/DESCRIPTION) file (this is where the dependencies are stated) you see only:

```
Depends: R (>= 3.1.0)
```

So `rjson` package needs only R newer or equal than 3.1.0 to run.

Answer (score 3):

Just as EDi has stated, the list states packages that depend on rjson.
I think [kintone](https://www.kintone.com/) has been knocked off the list, since the cloud service itself is not dependent on rjson. The [R SDK for kintone](https://github.com/yamaryu0508/r-kintone) though, is dependent on rjson, as shown in the README of the GitHub page.

So in this case, if I wanted to run kintone's APIs using this R SDK, I would also need the rjson package for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method of finding the actual (not just documented in CRAN) reverse dependencies of a given R package is by using `dependsOnPkgs()` function from the `tools` R library (see [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/dependsOnPkgs.html)).

For example:

```
library(tools)

> cat(sort(tools::dependsOnPkgs("webshot")))
amanida BayesianNetwork behaviorchange CALANGO covid19sf dlookr heatmaply IntLIM iotables kableExtra LifeInsuranceContracts makepipe manipulateWidget mapedit mapview modelsummary nomnoml RGISTools tab ufs wilson
```

As compared with the CRAN documentation for the downstream `webshot` library:

> Reverse dependencies:

> Reverse imports: antaresViz, ari, BETS, BioM2, flow, GALLO, heatmaply, kableExtra, manipulateWidget, namedropR, nomnoml, oceanis, oncrawlR, PathoStat, Prostar, reactablefmtr, tableHTML, tidycwl, trelliscopejs, vegalite

> Reverse suggests: asteRisk, autoshiny, bayesPO, BED, behaviorchange, bookdown, CIMICE, codebook, drake, ELMER, enrichTF, esATAC, ggiraphExtra, hablar, HYPEtools, iheatmapr, knitr, lavaanExtra, makepipe, mapview, microPop, modeltime, MODIStsp, NGLVieweR, optimall, pGRN, pkgnet, plotly, r2d3, radiant.data, rENA, rtweet, sdcTable, sentopics, simlandr, sortable, sparrow, spectralAnalysis, starsTileServer, tiler, ubiquity, validata, visNetwork, wordcloud2, xpose

[source: [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/index.html)]

As we see from the above example, the reverse dependencies lists on CRAN are only loosely connected to the actual dependency graph (here: in an environment containing a representative "sample" of all 4.9k R libraries from CRAN Task Views), and not just "reverse imports", but also "reverse suggests" lists may contain actual reverse dependencies that would likely break without the downstream package (here: `webshot`).